# My aunt likes food, but not drinks

Tags: pattern

My aunt likes some things, but not others:

- She likes food, but not drinks.
- She likes to create, but not to paint.
- She has a boat, but would never want a car.
- She likes to pogo, but not to jump.
- She likes to devour, but not to eat.
- She likes inuits, but not navajos.

**What type of things does my aunt like?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps, like herself, your aunt likes things which

> have equal numbers of vowels and consonants.
>  Food, create, boat, pogo, devour & inuits do unlike drinks, paint, jump, eat & navajos.
>  (Inuits/navajos added after hexomino's earlier solution which otherwise worked.)

Comment: as a bonus, *some* but not *others* also fits the pattern

Comment: Nice spot @somebody and well chosen words by Auribouros.

Answer (score 5):

I think you aunt likes

> Words which have at least three enclosed regions

Explanation

> If we look at the letters **a, b, d, e, g, o, p, q,** we see that each of them encloses a region ("has a hole") and that, in the words your aunt likes, there are at least three instances, whereas there are at most two in the ones she does not like.

Comment: Even though it fits, my aunt likes inuits, but not navajos!